# Ruby on rails Resque db connection error while starting queue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

while i try to start resque queue by **rake resque:work QUEUE='*'**
i am getting "database configuration does not specify adapter" error.
db connection is okay i guess because it can fetch data and shows in index page.
and ... there are queued tasks i can see in ~/resque/overview but it doesn't executes.

the full error msg is:

```
Initializing connection to redis...
Done (port = 6392)!
Configuring resque sheduler... 
Resque scheduler configured
rake aborted!
database configuration does not specify adapter
/home/woody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:47:in `resolve_hash_connection'
/home/woody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:41:in `resolve_string_connection'
/home/woody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:27:in `spec'
/home/woody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:130:in `establish_connection'
/home/woody/Workspace/IDP/Amigos/app/models/ak.rb:2
/home/woody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `load'
/home/woody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `load_file'
/home/woody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:639:in `new_constants_in'
/home/woody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:468:in `load_file'
/home/woody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:353:in `require_or_load'
/home/woody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'
/home/woody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
/home/woody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `eager_load!'
/home/woody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
/home/woody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `eager_load!'
/home/woody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
/home/woody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
/home/woody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/resque-1.24.1/lib/resque/tasks.rb:61
/home/woody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14
Tasks: TOP => resque:work => resque:preload
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the contents of the error message, can you verify what your `database.yml` file looks like? Does each environment have an associated adapter (such as sqlite3, mysql2, etc.)?

Comment: my database.yml file looks like...
`development: &development
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: idp
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 
  host: 127.0.0.1
  socket: "3306"`